# Can Textmate detect file type before saving?

Tags: textmate

Is there a way to make Textmate recognize the file type automatically *before saving*?

I often create a new file for the purposes of quickly testing code and it would be nice if I didn't have to select the file type from the status bar dropdown. The reason it seems like a silly step is because after I type the line

`<?php`

it should automatically set the file type association.

Comment: Completely agree. I love textmate, I just wish they had a quicker release cycle. Something like full screen mode and a built in sFTP browser would be amazing.